# Apply order by on data return

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I have a stored procedure which return data like this

```
ReportLabelID   AssessmentLinkId
TextBox7            10207
RadioButton2        10207
TextArea2           10207
FullName5           10207
FullName5           10211
RadioButton2        10211
TextArea2           10211
TextBox7            10211
```

What I want is that to sort the return data in alphabetical order along with their AssessmentLinkId in order also something like this

```
ReportLabelID   AssessmentLinkId
FullName5           10207
RadioButton2        10207
TextArea2           10207
TextBox7            10207
FullName5           10211
RadioButton2        10211
TextArea2           10211
TextBox7            10211
```

Comment: `ORDER BY AssessmentLinkID, ReportLabelID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Marc B above

```
ORDER BY AssessmentLinkID, ReportLabelID
```

did the trick for me thanks